# How to open Instagram image in Fancybox popup?

Tags: jquery, fancybox, instagram

Is it possible to open Instagram image with Fancybox? Current version I have is 2.1.5, but any will do.

Here is Codepen example, first image is for Instagram and it doesn't work, the second one is something else and it works ok. I am guessing this is because of missing .jpeg extension? How can I make it work?

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XExyKO

```
<a class="fancybox" href="https://www.instagram.com/p/BWFOf3KAJgg/">
    <img src="https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/vp/789ad577697b12f9abc70523e1082feb/5B4FA13F/t51.2885-15/s320x320/e35/19534600_2014027525491841_4032380537485131776_n.jpg">
</a>
```

```js
$("a.fancybox").fancybox({});
```

Comment: It doesn't work because it links to the instagram *page*, not the image. Also note that you shouldn't really be hotlinking content either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to either load media module or upgrade to v3 where it is already built in. Upgrade and simply use `data-fancybox="gallery"` attributes for your links to make it work automagically.

See this demo - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aYRQEo?editors=1000

Answer (score 0):

You are just simply using the wrong link see picture or copy this "https://scontent-arn2-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/5a125810ce05d6042f395e7d0bb4482d/5B529958/t51.2885-15/e35/19534600_2014027525491841_4032380537485131776_n.jpg"[image]